# Saving data from a drop down list in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I created a menu page where it has a drop down menu with a list of menus from the database and it also has a textbox to enter new menus.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to figure out how to save my dropdown. So for example I have a menu called "About Us" in the drop down list and I want to create a new menu called "Team", and "Team" is a child of "About Us"

So in my table I would have something like this

```
 id | parent | title
------------------------
 1  | NULL   | About Us
 2  | 1      | Team
```

Menu Controller

```
function get_data_from_post()
{
    $data['title'] = $this->input->post('title', TRUE);
    $data['parent'] = $this->input->post('parent', TRUE);


    if(!isset($data)){
        $data = '';
    }

    return $data;
}

function get_data_from_db($update_id)
{
    $query = $this->get_where($update_id);

    foreach($query->result() as $row){
        $data['title'] = $row->title;
        $data['parent'] = $row->parent;
    }

    return $data;
}

function create()
{
    $update_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $submit = $this->input->post('submit', TRUE);

    if($submit == "Submit"){
        //person has submitted the form
        $data = $this->get_data_from_post();
    }else{
        if(is_numeric($update_id)){
            $data = $this->get_data_from_db($update_id);
        }
    }

    if(!isset($data)){
        $data = $this->get_data_from_post();
    }


    //$titles = array();

    $query = $this->get('title');
    foreach($query->result() as $row){
        $titles[] = $row->title;
    }

    $data['titles'] = $titles;

    $data['update_id'] = $update_id;

    $data['view_file'] = "create";
    $this->load->module('templates');
    $this->templates->admin_template($data);
}

function submit()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required|xss_clean');

    if($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE){
        $this->create();
    }else{
        $data = $this->get_data_from_post();



        $update_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

        if(is_numeric($update_id)){
            $this->_update($update_id, $data);
        }else{
            $this->_insert($data);
        }

        redirect('menus/manage');
    }
}
```

create.php view

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h2>Create Menus</h2>   
    <h5>Welcome Jhon Deo , Need to make dynamic. </h5>
</div>
</div>

<hr />

<?php
    echo validation_errors("<p style='color: red;'>", "</p>");
    echo form_open('menus/submit/'.$update_id);
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
    <select name="menus">
        <?php
            foreach($titles as $title){

                echo "<option value=".$title.">".$title."</option>";
            }
        ?>
        </select>


    </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Title</label>
            <!-- <input class="form-control" /> -->
            <?php
                $data = array(
                            'name' => 'title',
                            'id' => 'title',
                            'value' => $title,
                            'class' => 'form-control',
                        );

                echo form_input($data);
            ?>
        </div>

        <?php

            $data = array(
                'name' => 'submit',
                'id' => 'submit',
                'value' => 'Submit',
                'class' => 'btn btn-success',
                'style' => 'width: 100%',
            );

            echo form_submit($data);
        ?>
    </form>
</div>
</div> 
<?php    
    echo form_close();
?>
```

UPDATE:
this is what I have when I print_r($titles)

```
Array
(
    [0] => About Us
    [1] => Home
)
```

If there is anything you don't understand or if you need me to give more information please let me know.

Comment: can you give us print_r($titles)

Answer (score 0):

You should have declared a model. From there, you can create a function that will save the values in the database that you initialize via controller. You should utilize the MVC pattern of it. CodeIgniter has a great documentation to read about what I am pointing out.. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html?highlight=model